# rostest: fails when using ROS_HOSTNAME (single PC)

Tags: ros, rostest, ros-kinetic, ros-hostname, ros-ip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My rostest fails with this error:

```
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [mypc.local]
```

It does not fail consistently in the same place.

I have no problems with:

```
ping mypc.local
```

However, rostest succeeds when run like this:

```
roscore &
rostest --reuse-master foo foo.test
```

And it also succeeds when doing:

```
unset ROS_HOSTNAME
export ROS_IP=<my IP address>
rostest foo foo.test
```

... but I do not want to maintain a fixed IP, that's the whole point of DNS!

1. Why is ROS_HOSTNAME not working for my rostest?
2. Why is the failure not consistent? Could this be a symptom of a parameter server with too high load?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285827/rostest:-fails-when-using-ros_hostname-(single-pc)/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:
Intermittent failures in hostname resolution could cause this. The fact that `ping` works does not guarantee your infrastructure is ok. Is `mypc.local` set in `/etc/hosts`, or is a DNS serving that domain? `ROS_IP` working always would seem to point to problems with DNS.

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-03-19**:
Thanks. I have only `mypc` in `/etc/hosts`. If I add `mypc.local`, my rostest works. But I guess I still will have the problem in a multi-machine scenario, where other machines tries to lookup `mypc.local`?
Do you know of any tools to test the consistency of hostname resolution?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:
.. experience with any tools in particular, so can't recommend any.

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-03-19**:
Can you explain why my rostest works with the `--reuse-master` option?
In all the above, does it matter what `ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to? (It is `http://localhost:11311`)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:\

> Can you explain why my rostest works with the `--reuse-master` option?

No.

> In all the above, does it matter what `ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to? (It is `http://localhost:11311`)

you should not need to set `ROS_MASTER_URI` unless:

- this is a multi-homed system and the default doesn't work.

..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:\

- this is a multi-host ROS application

`localhost` is fine, as long as you have a `roscore` running that is reachable via that hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it works when you add the hostname to `/etc/hosts` that would definitely point to a DNS issue. Whether that is on your machine or with the DNS, I don't know.

> Do you know of any tools to test the consistency of hostname resolution?

No, sorry. I'm sure they exist, but I don't have any ..

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1